# Read Only fields on a tabular form

Tags: apex

I am not sure if this may have already been answered. I have a tabular form for data entry. The form has a [sequence] field, a [start_date] field, an [end_date] field and a [task] field. The task field is a select list of tasks. Upon selecting a task, is it possible to void out the [start_date] field, without having to refresh the page?

So if I choose a specific task, the [start_date] field automatically becomes read only, or greyed out or voided out. Not too sure how to handle this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. THanks

Version 4.2.1

Comment: What is version 4.2.1 referring to?

Answer (score 1):

I would try it with some javascript without using any reRender functions on the page. In my example if user selects value 2 - the input date field becomes `disabled` attribute:

```
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"/>

<apex:form >

<apex:outputLabel value="Select Value:" for="MyVal"/>
<apex:selectList size="1" multiselect="false" id="MyVal">
    <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Value 1" itemValue="1"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Value 2" itemValue="2"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Value 3" itemValue="3"/>
</apex:selectList>

<apex:outputLabel value="Account Date:" for="MyDate"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!acc.MyDate__c}" id="MyDate"/>


<script>
    jQuery('[id$=MyVal]').bind('change', function(){
        if(jQuery(this).val() == 2){
            jQuery('[id$=MyDate]').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
        else{
            jQuery('[id$=MyDate]').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
</script>

</apex:form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I will see if I can incorporate this into my application. I was affraid of the fact that I might need to incorporate some javascript, as we try to avoid uding direct javascript code in our applications, but thank you nonetheless. I shall see what happens.

Comment: @user2595 And it works? If yes - please check this answer as the right solution for your question.